# Subir informações de uma branch depois de dias

Tags: git

Eu tenho 2 áreas de desenvolvimento: **homologação** e **produção**. Geralmente antes de subir para produção eu subo para a homologação para realizar teste ( acredito que geral faça isso )  até aqui tudo OK.

Porem vou subir um layout novo para um site e gostaria de usa-lo por alguns dias na homologação antes, e a duvida é: Pelo `GIT` eu crio uma `branch` nova, subo para o homologação e depois de 1 semana eu consigo subir essa mesma `branch` para a produção?

Comment: Acredito seja isso sim. eu faço exatemente a mesma coisa, a unica diferença que tenho 3 branchs de release, dev, tests e stable, agora se estiver 'errado' vou descobrir também, mas acredito que esteja correto.

Comment: Você já não faz isso como explicou anteriormente? Testando antes na homologação e depois fazendo o deploy em produção. Qual a dificuldade?

Answer (score 1):

Como o layout é experimental, você pode fazer como disse:

1. Criar uma branch apenas com o novo layout
2. Subir ela para homologação
3. Dando tudo certo, você pode fazer o merge desta branch para a branch de produção (o que seria equivalente ao que disse)

Outra ideia seria manter os dois layouts (antigo e novo) na sua aplicação e controlar a habilitação de uma ou outra, via parâmetro. Esta estratégia é conhecida como *Toggle Feature*. Assim, você pode já subir o código para a branch de produção e ligar este parâmetro, para habilitar o layout novo, em homologação.